# Ассемблер. Массив в аргументах функции

Tags: ассемблер, nasm, sasm

Функция получает на вход аргументы:

1. Массив с 16-битовыми значениями.
2. Количество элементов в массиве.
3. Значение x.

Функция должна вернуть количество элементов, которые больше x. Я пытаюсь получить доступ к элементу массива, но получаю ошибку.

```
%include "rw32-2018.inc"

section .data
array dw 384,64,80,208,144,48,-768,-768

section .text
CMAIN:
     push ebp
     mov ebp,esp

     push 0
     push 8
     push array   
     call function
     pop ebp
     ret
function:
     mov eax, 0
     mov esi, 0
     mov edx, [ebp+8] ;(array)
     cmp edx, 0
         je error_end
     mov ecx, [ebp+12] ; (N elements in array)
     cmp ecx, 0
         jl error_end
     mov ebx, [ebp+16] ; X value
     while:
         mov edi, [edx+esi*2]; Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
         cmp edi, ebx
             jg inc_eax
         inc_eax: inc eax
             jng go_on

         go_on:
         inc esi        
         cmp esi, ecx
             jl while

         mov  esp,ebp ; stack-frame leave
         pop  ebp     ; stack-frame leave
         ret  16      ; stdcall

      error_end: mov eax, -1
                 ret 16
```

Использую SASM с компилятором NASM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вкратце: программа не работает, потому что в функции `function` вы забыли добавить пролог.

В прологе сохраняется значение указателя стека по состоянию на начало работы функции. Т.к. пролога нет, то используется значение `ebp`, которое установлено в вызывающей функции `CMAIN` (значение `esp` до входа в функцию и до отправки аргументов в стек). Что происходит по мере выполнения программы (помним, что стек растет в сторону **меньших** адресов, при `push` сначала `esp` уменьшается, потом по адресу `[esp]` кладется значение):

```
 mov ebp, esp ; пока что esp == ebp
 push 0  ; значение esp уменьшается на 4, по адресу [esp] кладется 0, esp == ebp - 4
 push 8  ; ..., esp == ebp - 8
 push array  ; esp == ebp - 12
 call function  ; значение esp уменьшается на 4, в стек кладется адрес возврата, происходит переход на функцию
```

После входа в функцию `esp == ebp - 16`

Отсюда получается, что:

- По адресу `[esp]` лежит адрес возврата из функции
- Адрес массива лежит по адресу `[esp+4]` (на момент входа в функцию) или `[ebp-12]`
- Размер массива лежит по адресу `[esp+8]` или `[ebp-8]`
- Значение x лежит по адресу `[esp+12]` или `[ebp-4]`

Получается, что по факту по адресу `[ebp+8]` лежит не то что вы ожидали, какие-то совершенно посторонние данные. Вы эти данные интерпретируете как адрес (что примерно эквивалентно обращению по неинициализированному указателю в С/С++), происходит обращение к диапазону адресов, неразрешенных для вашей программы, получаем segfault.

Что нужно поправить кроме пролога:

- для правильного выравнивания стека (по соглашению stdcall) значение операнда у `ret` должно равняться размеру аргументов, т.е. должно быть `ret 12` (3 аргумента по 4 байта).
- если в функции есть пролог, то перед каждым `ret` в этой функции должен выполниться эпилог (у вас в функции эпилог только перед одним из `ret`). Если эпилог не добавить, то из стека не будет вытащено сохраненное значение `ebp`, которое командой `ret` будет проинтерпретировано как адрес возврата, и возврат произойдет в область стека, а дальше исполнение данных как кода, все плохо (хотя скорее всего стек будет защищен от исполнения, и программа упадет с исключением).

Вот вариант с минимальными исправлениями (компилируется с помощью fasm):

```
include 'win32ax.inc'

.data
array dw 384,64,80,208,144,48,-768,-768

.code
CMAIN:
    ; В этой функции пролог/эпилог не нужны, т.к. аргументов и локальных переменных нет
    push 0
    push 8
    push array
    call function
    ret

function:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    ; после выполнения пролога в [ebp] сохраненное значение регистра ebp,
    ; в [ebp+4] - адрес возврата, в [ebp+8] - адрес массива, и т.д.

    mov eax, 0
    mov esi, 0
    mov edx, [ebp+8] ;(array)
    cmp edx, 0
        je error_end
    mov ecx, [ebp+12] ; (N elements in array)
    cmp ecx, 0
        jl error_end
    loop_start:
        mov edi, [edx+esi*2]
        cmp edi, ebx
            jg inc_eax
        inc_eax: inc eax
            jng go_on

        go_on:
        inc esi
        cmp esi, ecx
            jl loop_start

    mov  esp,ebp
    pop  ebp
    ret  12

    error_end: mov eax, -1
    ; если точек выхода несколько, то в каждой должен быть эпилог перед ret (если был пролог в начале функции)
    mov  esp,ebp
    pop  ebp
    ret 12

.end CMAIN
```